# ServiceStack Authentication Error Codes

Tags: authentication, servicestack

Before i've always catch up every authentication xhr request rejection globally.

The status codes was the following:

```
401: not Authenticated
403: not Authorized
419: sessionTimeout
440: sessionTimeout
```

Using the `CredentialsAuthProvider` i get an `401` for a invalid username or password for a login request. For `[Authenticate]` `401` Unauthorized. What can i except for `403`, `419`, `440` sessionTimeout etc. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `403 Forbidden` is returned when Users are authenticated but they don't have authorization to use a Service, e.g. they don't have the necessary [Roles or Permissions](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization#requiredrole-and-requiredpermission-attributes).

Session Timeouts are never thrown in ServiceStack as Sessions are automatically removed when they're expired by the [back-end Caching Provider](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Caching) which results in the same state as never having a session at all, so it returns `401 Unauthorized`.

Wikipedia has a good list of the different [HTTP Status codes and their meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).